# Ordenación de datos según dependencias

Tags: python, algoritmos, recursión

Tengo una diccionario en donde almaceno información de tablas de una base de datos, el nombre de la tabla lo utilizo como clave del *dict* principal.

Dentro de cada elemento almaceno como atributos el tipo de tabla que pueden ser: **debil** o **fuerte**, el orden (*valor que pretendo calcular*) y las **dependencias** que serían las tablas que están relacionadas como foráneos.

```
tablas = {
    'articulos':{
        'tipo':'debil',
        'orden': 0,
        'dependencias':[
            {'tabla':'lineas', 'orden':0},
            {'tabla':'grupos', 'orden':0},
            {'tabla':'categorias', 'orden':0},
            {'tabla':'marcas', 'orden':0}
        ]
    },
    'marcas':{
        'tipo':'debil',
        'orden': 0,
        'dependencias':[
            {'tabla':'paises', 'orden': 0}
        ]
    },
    'paises':{
        'tipo':'fuerte',
        'orden': 0,
        'dependencias':[]
    },
    'lineas':{
        'tipo':'fuerte',
        'orden':0,
        'dependencias':[]
    },
    'grupos':{
        'tipo':'debil',
        'orden':0,
        'dependencias':[
            {'tabla':'lineas', 'orden':0}
        ]
    },
    'categorias':{
        'tipo': 'fuerte',
        'orden': 0,
        'dependencias': []
    }
}
```

Lo que pretendo es encontrar el orden de prioridad según su dependencia, es decir, si la tabla articulos tiene dependencias, estas deben estar en un orden inicial ya que son necesarias para la creación de dicha tabla.

Para encontrar el orden me propuse calcular primero los que tienen el tipo **fuerte** ya que estas no tienen dependencias.

```
orden = 1
# calcular orden de tablas fuertes
for tabla in tablas:
    if tablas[tabla]['tipo'] == 'fuerte':
        tablas[tabla]['orden'] = orden
        orden += 1
```

De esa manera logro asignar el orden a las tablas que son de tipo fuerte.

El problema es al tratar de asignar un orden a aquellas tablas que tienen dependencias y que estas dependencias tengan de vuelta dependencias, etc, etc.

El siguiente código estoy probando, pero no consigo avanzar.

```
# calcular orden de tablas debiles
def calcularOrdenDependencias(tabla):
    for dependencia in tablas[tabla]['dependencias']:
        if tablas[dependencia['tabla']]['tipo'] == 'debil':
            # ¿en esta parte debería volver a llamar a la función
            # calcularOrdenDependencias?
            pass 


for tabla in tablas:
    if tablas[tabla]['tipo'] == 'debil':
        calcularOrdenDependencias(tabla)
```

Creo que la clave está en encontrar primero el orden de las dependencias y después asignar el orden a la tabla según el valor máximo de orden de entre todas sus dependencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, tu problema es encontrar un orden (de creación?) de las tablas. Creo que se podría resolver si damos un "peso" a cada tabla, según las dependencias que tenga. El concepto de "peso" es un poco distinto al del "orden" que parece es el que buscas definir, el "peso" no indica necesariamente un orden: dentro de las tablas de un mismo "peso", no nos importa el orden. Además, el concepto `débil` o `fuerte` es redundante si justamente tenemos un `peso`, las tablas de `peso = 1` son las que denominas "fuertes" cualquier otra sería "débil".

Coloquialmente hablando, una vez definido el peso de cada tabla:

1. Primero crearíamos las tablas con `peso = 1`, es decir aquellas sin dependencias.
2. Luego eventualmente crearíamos las que tienen `peso = 2`, que no son más que aquellas que tienen una sola dependencia con una tabla de peso 1 (si tuviera una dependencia con una tabla de peso 2 el peso en realidad sería de 3 y no de 2).
3. Luego seguimos avanzando a las tablas con los pesos siguientes y así hasta completar.

Para calcular este "peso" podemos hacer una función recursiva:

```
def calcular_peso(tablas, tabla, peso=0):
  peso = peso + 1
  for t in [e["tabla"] for e in tablas[tabla]["dependencias"]]:
    peso = calcular_peso(tablas,t, peso)
  return(peso)
```

- Esta rutina recibe, tu diccionario `tablas` y una tabla en particular de la que se desea calcular el peso.
- Ten en cuenta que Python por defecto tiene un máximo de niveles de recursión, que si mal no recuerdo es de 1000 (eventualmente se podría modificar)

La idea entonces sería, calcular el "peso" de cada tabla y luego transformar estas en una lista y ordenarlas por el "peso", de las más "livianas" a las más "pesadas". Por ejemplo:

```
for t in tablas:
  tablas[t]["peso"] = calcular_peso(tablas, t)

lista_final = sorted([(t,tablas[t]["peso"]) for t in tablas],key=lambda x: x[1])
print(lista_final)
```

El resultado final:

```
[('paises', 1), ('lineas', 1), ('categorias', 1), ('marcas', 2), ('grupos', 2), 
('articulos', 7)]
```

- Las tablas "fuertes" (sin dependencias) tienen un peso de 1
- `articulos` tiene un peso de 7, si gráficamos el árbol de dependencias podemos verificarlo:

  ```
  articulos (1)
     lineas (2)
     grupos (3)
        lineas (4)
     categorias (5)
     marcas (6)
       paises (7)
  ```

**Importante**: te sugiero que pruebes este algoritmo con un conjunto de datos mayor y más complejo para terminar de validarlo.

Comment: Utilizar el concepto de peso es muy práctico y con las pruebas que estuve realizando hasta con 300 tablas con dependencias multinivel ha realizado correctamente los cálculos de cada elemento. Muchas gracias por tu aporte!, saludos!